# Can I use a SkinnedMeshRenderer animation in a Canvas?

Tags: unity, 2d

I just downloaded an asset from the store: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/67122

They're just animated characters. If you drag & drop the prefabs on the scene, it works fine.

The thing is, I work exclusively with Unity's new 2D Canvas/Image/Button/etc. These prefabs instead use a `SkinnedMeshRenderer` so it's not like you can put them inside your Canvas.

I want to have the prefabs work in my Canvas. For all intents and purposes I want those animations to act like a `Image` inside the Canvas.

This is what one of those prefabs looks like:

[image]

I want to take advantage of the Unity's canvas because it makes a lot of things easier - like scaling for all devices, scroll views, easy masks, etc.